# Flutter audioplayers plugin - how to play online radio from this link?

Tags: flutter, audio-player, internet-radio

I am trying to use the [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) plugin in flutter to play the radio at the following link

https://video2b.vixtream.net/radio/v/fbcfm

I tried setting the url but that doesn't work.

I am not sure how to extract the streaming url and set it in the AudioPlayer.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use flutter radio package. It will full fill your requirements. Check working flutter app here...
[Source code](https://cutt.ly/flutter-radio)

[image: Watch the video]